# SyntaxError using gdata-python to get worksheets feed

Tags: python, gdata, gdata-python-client

I'm getting an occasional error when trying to fetch a list of worksheets from gdata.  This does not happen for all spreadsheets, but will consistently happen to the same spreadsheet for a period of several days to weeks. I suspected permissions, but was unable to find any special permissions for the spreadsheets that cause the error. I'm using OAuth2, gdata 2.0.18, and Python 2.6.8.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/shared_from_host/snake/base/fetchers/google_spreadsheet/common.py", line 176, in get_worksheet_list
    feed = client.get_worksheets(spreadsheet_id)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/snakeenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gdata/spreadsheets/client.py", line 108, in get_worksheets
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/snakeenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gdata/client.py", line 640, in get_feed
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/snakeenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gdata/client.py", line 278, in request
    version=get_xml_version(self.api_version))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/snakeenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/atom/core.py", line 520, in parse
    tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)
  File "<string>", line 86, in XML
SyntaxError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

This seems to be from the request getting an empty string as the response.

Does anybody have any idea on why this might not work, or troubleshooting ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Submitting your code is always helpful when asking why your code isn't working.